# Increase SQL Compact Edition Read Speed

Tags: wpf, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a wpf application that saves items in a SQL Server Compact Edition file.
This file is created dynamically from a list of classes that make up the data context.
I'm experiencing slow load times when I have the following scenario.

Trying to load a list of ItemA that contains a List of ItemB

In my datacontext this links to Table1, A Link Table From Table1 To Table2 and Table2

To get this into my application I Load All Table1 rows from Sql Server.
For Each Table1 row returned I add any information to a New ItemA. I then look for any Table2 rows that link to the current Table1 row via the link table.  For All Table2 rows returned I convert them to a list of ItemB's and add them to ItemA.

I eventually end up with a list of ItemA, each object containing a list of ItemB.  The problem is I'm making multiple calls to the DB and this is pushing up load times when getting to a few hundred items.
Is there a better way of doing this without the multiple calls?
If not what's the best way to speed up the app? Should I be Caching ItemA, if so what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Based on no answers so far and the fact that the only way I've managed to speed up the App (1 minute load time to milliseconds) is by binary serializing all my objects to disk and back into memory on load, I'm thinking of throwing away SQL server CE completely.  I want to port this App to Windows 8 Metro eventually and as it doesn't support sql ce that seems an even more compelling reason to do so. - Does anyone have any advice on how big my serialized file can grow before it starts becoming unworkable or have any other reasons why this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much of an answer but I believe that sql ce isn't fast enough for the scenario raised above.  I therefore changed my backing store to an in memory list that is serialized to file as per my comment above.
After a month of testing I haven't experienced any issues and have dramatically improved the speed of my application.